# How do I recursively grep files in multiple folders? I'm unable to pipe the recursive cat output

Tags: bash, recursion, awk, grep, cat

I have 4 folders, `set1, set2, set3, set4`).

Each folder has 1 file called `result.txt`.

Contents of each of the result files look like this:

```
result is:
score=19
```

i'm able to recursively cat the file contents with this 1 liner.

```
find . -iname "result.txt" -exec cat {} \;
```

**Question is:**

> How do I recursively pipe the `cat` output into `grep` and *add those
> scores*?

**Expected Output:**

> Combined Score = 251

*(Add all scores in each of the result.txt files
45+100+87+19)*

playground link: https://repl.it/repls/SatisfiedBeigeListener

[image]

Comment: add all the scores

Comment: Please show expected output in question to make it cllear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to mathematically add all scores and print `sum`:

```
cd files # parent directory of set1, set2, set3, set4

awk -F= '$1 == "score" { sum += $2 } END { print sum }' */result.txt
```

```
251
```